# Interpretation of the reachability plot (optics clustering))

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, python, graph-theory

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#optics

Does anyone know to read the reachability plot produced in optics clustering? What indicators exist that allow the user to evaluate the results of optics clustering using the reachability plot?

Thanks!

[image: optics reachability plot in python]